# Difference between date and jsdate object

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, datepicker

I have integrated Mydatepicker on my angular 4 app where I have a calendar integrated on a page, when I select a date call a REST api with post method sending timestamp of chosen date to get the result from API

I checked the date and timestamp in console and found that jsdate object return previous date from selected , following is my object logged on date selecte

```
date: Object { year: 2017, month: 11, day: 25 }
epoc: 1511548200
formatted: "25.11.2017"
jsdate: Date 2017-11-24T18:30:00.000Z
proto: Object { … }
```

How do it correct this ? is there any configuration to control it or if its correct way then how can I handle this issue ?

Comment: `Object { year: 2017, month: 11, day: 25 }` is not a Date object. Its a normal object with properties of a date. `Date 2017-11-24T18:30:00.000Z` is a Date Object. Also, if you are `2017-11-24` and saying its returning previous date, you are missing timestamp value `T18:30:00.000Z`. If you try to create a date object using this value, you will get proper date. Try `jsdate.getDate()`

Comment: We have no idea what you send, what api expects etc?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes but It doesnt matter what API takes, I just consoled the datepicker output, I mentioned API just for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Just updated the question and removed API part

Comment: Of course it matters if what you send returns data from a  different day. A timestamp doesn't indicate if it is utc time or not whereas the date string shown does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. This is the JavaScript way to handle dates.

Formatted date represents selected date on date-picker however your system can have a different timezone setup and hence relative date time for selected date will be different for GMT, and this is what jsdate stands for

jsdate : represents date time object for GMT

If you want to get the actual selected date then you need to generate it with getDay , getMonth etc or you can adjust with timezone offset.

Adjusting timezone offset could be a better options as it will work on all system and timezone.

With epoc and https://www.epochconverter.com/ it can be checked how much difference is there in your time and GMT for the selected date time timestamp

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will help to work with with javascript date object